The prime race $a_i \mod 11$ vs $b_i \mod 11$ conjecture
Let $f(n,a)$ be the number of primes of type residue $a \mod 11$ between $1$ and
$n$.
Is it true that for all $n>1$ we have
$$f(n,1)+f(n,2)+f(n,3)+f(n,5)+f(n,7)+f(n,6)+f(n,8) > f(n,4)+f(n,9)+f(n,10) $$
Let me explain the weird sum order of the LHS : I took the first 7 noncomposite integers mod 11, apart from 11 itself.
So for small $n$ it must hold anyway.
The idea is that is must always hold.
The left side has 7 sums and the right side only 3.
It reminds us of the chebychev bias I guess.
Is there an easy way to show this ?
So without making many computations and simple tests ?
For very large $n$ this holds ofcourse since in the limit the ratio equals $1$ for any $a,b$ ;
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n,a)}{f(n,b)} = 1$$

Your function $f(n,a)$ is more commonly written as $\pi(x;11,a)$. From your last sentence it seems like you know the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions.

Of the many explicit bounds for the prime number theorem in arithmetic progressions in the literature, a few can be found in Section 1 of my paper with Bennett, O'Bryant, and Rechnitzer that reduce this problem to a finite computation.

I verified the claim for $n<10^9$. The bounds in the paper linked above apply for $n>838,079,951$ and should be more than strong enough in this case. This should form a complete proof.

@GregMartin and anankEIpis thanks. But I assume a simpler method must exist for this here.

@mick I'd be interested in seeing one, but I'm doubtful.

@GregMartin Yeah I understand. We probably need a new way to look at it. Mathematicians or math has the habit of investigating the large numbers rather than the small. Especially when using limits.
